# file_get_contents() with modified HTTP headers returning garbage html output

Tags: php, dom, http-headers, file-get-contents, garbage

The following code is being used to extract html using SIMPLETHTMLDOM parser for php.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",                
    'header'=>"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml\r\n" .
              "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8\r\n" .
              "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n" .
              "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n",
    'user_agent'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.66 Safari/535.11\r\n"              
 )
)); 

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/cmbhav.htm', false, $context);
echo $html;

foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
    echo $e->href . '<br>';
```

**The output generated is Garbage html :**

```
‹µVßsâ6~Ï_¡s§¹ð2¹^:ìNˆÝ†)!ið=äéFØV"K>I˜pMÿ÷®lCšéÝKy@+í­¾ý´òè]t}‘ÜÝÄä2¹š’›Oãéä‚x]J'qò¥Q5š=ŸÒxæ…G£ÜÂ À2,·ÂÙ<&]YsËÁ 8eŒ%ãœU©*·#ÚØ¦“Ù$×°<* ôRc<¢AóänÏ/ã8!v[B`áÑRÔâ&Õ¼´D0¹Z³Þ=«X³è£SuohªŠBÉåZ¦¦wo¼pD“o*¦ 7“88ÉTº.@Ú¢ókà[ålþÓ­`[ÐæÀà,8yö_¸Pãí$ëŸHVñ³J÷XYÎXAð~Ö¤¬„÷ƒXŠÜ³óôTg/ "Wª×'ñÓSmÖgm‡€åJ’œÉL@¬µÒ'ò—»Ö’X½†áßdÃe¦6=%ÁéIðÒzH0«¸ÂìÍIgxô@>W¾|°´xäÃBÐ–5ãëèŽ,V©JÞËúççU0½â2ð‰Uå^n„ø*·¨j¦žÙ<ð±¾¯ˆt˜zùº.GxöjjìV AÅ _pÁívó,9$¥2H[%la”X[":zÐ/‡¤Ù´‘¿v5xô‡uªnÄ,}G6Ì3IÎÇÓ˜¤ „)YÊå ³](FÁ-—,Ëšåö4}ßÿ­Æ¿wÝî! 3V‘1²rn™¶†\‚†nõÿuÂ£æœ?ºÔí0p,³aQ{¡¤Åz“s ì_ÛÚ¬$8ó}R1ÁW2Àsï{O§7çQ4™ýŽ§t³ùÍùE3_ßFñ-.7ÕúøËi‹h°?øná£+%î…¬@ðdðáÅ^$Ì˜Àx3—&±¶ä˜‰ÃŸ¡óB‡ÇraÊaó&m§ÉU%¶Ž6//¼Ä™s Ç+;$;+l 5Ú6†Âg.­VÙº¾PÎ9Üõ¸ïô/,—U»^1ý–Lp®æ·²ËÁ{3    ¤;:Z•±ms€6RâVÈ>ÈaÓ­ñp˜à ¶BTs,¹uu‹Úzôý±M¢FñªÀKÄ¤ÅÞ]]ÐáAgÇíMèöiö*[ûN×Ç]±ÚJì@Î¹ÁfÈS&hüç§I2‰çôÔïŸÒ«ó[šþÏ8ºù_|$ªÞW^zï¶Ö@Â&ŒÔF Å2²ä—Hƒ¬CdD?ÿ‡\²ÅòÛ¹ ÑA.Ïø¤xÏ@¿Iè£7)à`pi¢¬Ét‰ÖÐæÄæ°gk0jB<=óšé4çºês>¿Ð.]Â¤Âhš ­›\jvìÒ¦æ”S8>Ñºï9‰V÷±W åu»ixH-[à—º¸ÇÀÍ‡Å?§m2“
```

Where am i doing Wrong !! I checked the headers info from fiddler. These are the actual header information when the link is opened with browser !!

```
[Client]
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.66 Safari/535.11
[Transport]
Host: www.nseindia.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: the garbage may be the zip'd html. Try to remove the HTTP-Header "Accept-Encoding.....". Is it plain text nao?

Comment: It looks like encoded data. Maby you should remove `"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n"` so you don't get gzipped content, or you could decompress it yourself using zlib functions. Oh @henchman was faster :)

Comment: Thanks, you should put that as an answer! V useful

Answer (score 0):

In the HTTP request you are explicitly declaring that you can handle compressed data, so that is what the server is returning:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n
```

You must now decode that compressed data:

```
$html = gzuncompress($html);
```

As `piotrekkr` mentions in a comment, you can alternatively remove the `Accept-Encoding` header and the web server should return plain text instead.