# Sending a golang HTTP request to a js file

Tags: go

When creating a HTTP request to a JavaScript file with this code, it returns the actual JS code itself just like it would when looking at the Network tab in the browser's developer tab.

```
var client = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.iana.org/_js/jquery.js", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36")
    
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println(string(body))
```

However, creating a request to the same URL, but defining all the request headers that would be used in the browser:

```
req.Header = http.Header{
        "Accept":          []string{"*/*"},
        "Accept-Encoding": []string{"gzip, deflate, br"},
        "Accept-Language": []string{"en-US,en;q=0.5"},
        "Cache-Control":   []string{"no-cache"},
        "Connection":      []string{"keep-alive"},
        "DNT":             []string{"1"},
        "Host":            []string{"www.iana.org"},
        "Pragma":          []string{"no-cache"},
        "Referer":         []string{"https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved"},
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest":  []string{"script"},
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode":  []string{"no-cors"},
        "Sec-Fetch-Site":  []string{"same-origin"},
    }
```

The response body returns a byte array that when converted to a string with `fmt.Println(string(body))` as in the first section of code, seems to be purely binary.

I'm trying to figure out if this binary response is the result of the JavaScript function itself (for example a token generator or whatever else the script's purpose could be) or whether it's something else.

Anyway, explanation or insight would be much appreciated <3

Comment: `"Accept-Encoding": []string{"gzip, deflate, br"},` this should give a lot of clue see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding). using that header is basically telling the server, "i want this thing in this form (gzip)."

Comment: Oh, so is the binary data essentially just the raw JavaScript function in a gzip archive? If so why does the browser not get an encoded response body? @BagusTesa

Comment: browsers do its magic and its done out of the box - unless you are using something from decades ago (IE6).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Http(s) request responds with garbage characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461602/https-request-responds-with-garbage-characters), [file_get_contents() with modified HTTP headers returning garbage html output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631596/file-get-contents-with-modified-http-headers-returning-garbage-html-output).

Comment: Alright I understand! Thank you two lots <3